# Can we use gpo to copy fold and multiple sub folder (with file)?

Tags: group-policy, microsoft

We have a folder and sub folder like this,

AAAA\

```
  AAAA_00\00.txt

  AAAA_01\01.txt

  AAAA_02\02.txt

  AAAA_03\03.txt
```

I am trying to set a gp with "File", the source is AAAA \ *, but actually, gp just makes a dir with AAAA, no sub folder and its file
if I want to copy AAAA and its sub folder (and file ), how to configure it?
I know if I configure 4 file gpo, it will be successful.
But if the number of the sub folder is very huge, how to configure it ?

Comment: sorry, i think no. it will be appreiciated  if you can point the most important solution point for this requests.

Comment: `[...] use a Robocopy startup script[...]`